# Обратиться к вложенному контролу TextBox в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

В ListBox имеется TextBox, в коде я пытаюсь изменить его текст

```
generalInfo.Text = "Ololo";
```

Ругается на generalInfo , как Cannot Resolve Simbol.  Код Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="charInfoBox"
             Margin="2,10,410,10"
             Background="{x:Null}"
             BorderBrush="Transparent"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CharTemplate}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CharTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="17"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{Binding Name,
                                                      FallbackValue=Name}" />
                            <!--  Имя чара  -->
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14"
                                       Foreground="#FFB9AE7B"
                                       Text="" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="generalInfo" FontSize="14"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="General Info" /></StackPanel></StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

Прошу помочь

Answer (score 2):

В DataTemplate можно только биндить поля контекста, обращаться напрямую - нельзя, это только шаблон элементов, которые потом отобразятся в ListBox.

Comment: Каким образом я могу изменить мое содержимое? дело в том что я делаю локализацию, уже написан класс с переводом, осталось только изменить эти элементы

Comment: Биндите текст в TextBlock на свойства ваших сущностей, а сущности уже должны строиться с учетом локализации. Если текст статичный, но с учетом локализации, то всё ещё проще - достаточно сослаться на ресурсы, WPF в рантайме сам вытащит ресурс нужной локализации. Ссылка будет выглядеть примерно так - `Text="{x:Static exres:Explorer.MyString}"/>`

Comment: хорошо, я попробую Ваш вариант, спасибо!